# Arrange data in cells of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display following datatable data in gridview in following format

```
PURCHASES A/C    10000 
SALES A/C        20000
SALES RETURN     30000
A1               40000
a2               50000
```

which grid event should i use to do this and how?

```
grid display:-
row1--PURCHASES A/C    10000   SALES A/C        20000
row2--                         SALES RETURN     30000
row3--A1               40000   a2               50000
```

Comment: Use Data Repeater instead of GridView, you can achieve it

Comment: how many entries has your data? Or are these 5 the only entries you want to display?

Comment: there can be 100s of entries like this..entries are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with one grid.  It'd be easier to split data in 2 collections and use 2 grids to show diff type of data.  hope this helps.

Comment: Also I'd recommend to into ListView and Repeater controls, you have more flexibility with these.

Comment: what is the logic behind this formatting?  I mean the rule which defines which row goes to the left and which to the right.

Comment: actuly its data of profit and loss report of accounting.it has a field called scode.if scode is same for some rows they will come one below the other..for ex..sale a/c and sale return..PURCHASES A/C ,a1 and a2 have different scodes..

Comment: Then I'd recommend based on this scode split you collection of data into 2 collections and arrange as needed.  Afterwards just use 2 grids to bind to these to 2 collections.

Comment: instead of splitting data and using two grids can i do it using a single repeater or datalist control?or i have to use third party gridcontrol?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`DataList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.aspx) instead. It has [`RepeatDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) and [`RepeatColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) properties. The former would be `RepeatDirection.Horizontal`  and the latter  2 in your case.

> Gets or sets the number of columns to display in the DataList control.